# How to Lay Concrete Slabs [900mm x 600mm x 50mm]

Tags: landscaping

I have a bunch of these concrete slabs to make a patio outside my garden house roughly 6ft width x 10ft length area. Can these be set on top of a sand screed [Slabs]

Also what gap in between is ideal in between slabs.

Can they also be doubled up on eachother to increase the height?

I have attached pictures

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The smallest gap between each is preferrable - unless you want to be constantly clearing bigger gaps that weeds will grow from. So, butting them up to each other is good. You may want to sprinkle some cement down the edges as a barrier, too, brushing off to tidy up.

Putting layers of slabs seems a waste. Either spread more sand first to bring the level up, or just leave them at the level they finish at. It's well worth spotting each slab with concrete in 5 spots to make levelling easier, and using a big rubber mallet to get them level - or perhaps sloping a little away from the shed, so rainwater will drain away from the foundations.

Comment: Not sure this is good advice. My experience is that butting slabs makes them difficult to level and causes spalling (chips flaking off where the edges touch). A small gap filled with sand, rock dust or grout avoids this. Dabs of concrete cause the slabs to be poorly supported and liable to cracking. It also creates a space for ants or rain to excavate below the slabs, further destabilising them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd lay them the same way you lay slate or bluestone.  Dig down, put some gravel down, put some sand on top of it, level it, then put the slabs down.

You will need at least a 1/4 inch gaps, both to make things level and for aesthetic purposes.  Put some rock dust between the slabs to keep the weeds down

Comment: +1 for gravel subbase with a layer of sand on top. Don't forget to put a border in place to contain the edges and stop the sand and gravel escaping.